# how to set permissions for app/cache and app/logs folders?

Tags: php, symfony

**Hi .. i am trying to change permissions for app/cache and app/logs folders  for my symfony2 project. even though i changed permissions for those folder, i am getting permission exception as bellow**:[image]

here is ls -l out put for those folders:
[image]

i am totally stuck here ..Please help to resolve this!! thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it is OS thing!!!** ..i am using cenOS 7 ..one of  its feature(SELinux) restricting apache user for write access.So that apache not able to write on cache directory.

solution i found is :

```
setenforce 0
```

..thank you everyone for your support!

Comment: If this solved the problem, you should accept your answer indeed.

Comment: be careful here you have totally disabled the SELinux feature, a better way is to allow apache in SELinux.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not on the `app/cache` folder (which seems ok from your screenshot), but on the `app/cache/dev` one.

Please try the following commands from shell (I suppose you are in the root folder of your Symfony2 install):

```
chmod -R 777 app/cache
chmod -R 777 app/logs
```

The `-R` flag will recurse subdirectories and should solve the permissions problem.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -la /var/www/html/Symfony/app/cache/`; the problem could also be related to one of the parent directories or the user under which Apache is running.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a user problem because permissions here are correct and the dev folder is created by symfony so it's not a recursive right problem.

Try that:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

For more informations see the symfony documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html